# Elements stuck in Linear Layout (Beginner)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I have started to learn Android Studio and have encountered a problem which I can't find a fix for.
I'm studying in a Udemy course and we're currently working in Linear Layout.
For some reason all my elements are automatically magnet to top of the layout and cannot be moved vertically.

I tried to run this question online, and was told to click a magnet icon (Auto connect to parent) but there is no such icon in my version (4.2.1)

Is there a solution for this (besides changing to relative or constraint layout?)

[Design mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meCO0.jpg)
[my XML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFzL8.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: Does this also happen when you run the app on an emulator or device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `android:orientation="vertical"` in LinearLayout

Comment: Glad it worked. Kindly Mark the answer for others to follow.